# error: asm operand type size(1) does not match type/size implied by constraint 'r'. On Duane Merrill's GPU radix sort

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, radix-sort

I have an error when I am trying to compile Merrill's radix sort under win-XP + VS2005.

error: asm operand type size(1) does not match type/size implied by constraint 'r'.

it occurs in the following code

```
#define B40C_DEFINE_GLOBAL_LOAD(base_type, dest_type, short_type, ptx_type, reg_mod)\
asm("ld.global.cg."#ptx_type" %0, [%1];" : "="#reg_mod(dest) : _B40C_ASM_PTR_(d_ptr + offset));\
...
B40C_DEFINE_GLOBAL_LOAD(char, signed char, char, s8, r)
```

Thanks

Comment: And what version of nvcc and toolchain are you using to compile this?

Comment: Thank you, Talonmies. I use toolkit v4.0 and my graphics card  is GT520 (Capability is 2.1). Is there any command (like "r") for s8?

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be caused by attempting to compile CUDA kernel code containing inline assembly instructions writing specifically for a 64 bit host platform on a 32 bit platform.

The CUDA toolchain ensures that `sizeof(void *)` is consistent on both host and device by emitting GPU code which matches the address mode of the host CPU. This particular code is assuming that pointers are 64 bit, whereas the code is being compiled in 32 bit host mode, leading to a size mismatch.